# What does this line mean in C# r => r.Item1?

Tags: c#, web-services

***r => r.Item1 == dFName***

Its part of this line

```
dFName = PropertyUtil.GetName<kUpdate>(r => r.Resolution);
fld2Lup = map.DTField2LookupMap[domType].First(r => r.Item1 == dFName );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is essentialy..

Return the First item of the "DTField2LookupMap[domType]" collection where the items property "Item1" is equal to dfName

this is a lambda expression: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx